# in array A, we have an inversion (i, j). why do we have at least j-i inversions in array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures, inversion

we have an array A that :
in array A exist a pair (i, j) that i<j and A[i]>A[j]. why do we have at least j-i inversions in array A?

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community!
Your question is not really understandable, please try to be more specific. You might want edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(i, j)` is one inversion. The other `j-i-1` involve the indices `k` such that `i<k<j`, since either `A[i]>A[k]` or `A[k]>A[j]` (otherwise, `A[i]<=A[k]<=A[k]`, which implies `A[i]<=A[j]` and contradicts the assumption that `A[i]>A[j]`).